# Kendo Grid MVC: default filter for string fields is set to "is equal to"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo Grid has default filter for "dt" field "is equal to" with calendar. For "name" field it has default filter "is equal to", but I want to move "Contains" to a first place of an option list and make it default for strings. How could it be implemented?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}


@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<MyClass>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(data =>
                  data.Ajax()
                      .ServerOperation(false)
                      .Read(read =>
                            read.Action("MyAction", "MyController"))
      )
      .Columns(cols =>
          {
              cols.Bound(x => x.dt).Title("Date").Width(150);
              cols.Bound(x => x.name).Title("Name").Width(250);
          })
      .Filterable()
      .Sortable())
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Filter menu customization](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html) demo. It appears you would do something along these lines:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<MyClass>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(data =>
                  data.Ajax()
                      .ServerOperation(false)
                      .Read(read =>
                            read.Action("MyAction", "MyController"))
      )
      .Columns(cols =>
          {
              cols.Bound(x => x.dt).Title("Date").Width(150);
              cols.Bound(x => x.name).Title("Name").Width(250);
          })
        .Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Extra(false)
            .Operators(ops => ops
                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                    .Contains("Contains")
                    .StartsWith("Starts with")
                    // any other filters you want in there
                    )))
      .Sortable())
```

If I'm interpreting it correctly, the `str.Clear()` clears out the filters that exist so you'll be building your own from there. So if you don't think the client needs or wants the `.EndsWith` filter, for example, you would not include it here.

Comment: While it solves the problem described in the question, it raises a new one, which is that the localizations specified in the locale .js files will no longer be applied to the respective strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code open kendo solution and find 
class name `StringOperators` under `Kendo.Mvc/UI/Grid/Settings`

In  `Operators = new Dictionary<string, string>()` 
change the order as you wish , reBuild the solution and then overwrite generated file in your project.

Comment: changing the source code directly will be overwritten every time you update the library.  This is a bad idea.