# Kendo Grid MVC doesn't respect filter order when filter list is complete

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I followed the solution provided here by Elsimer: [Kendo Grid MVC: default filter for string fields is set to "is equal to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487534/kendo-grid-mvc-default-filter-for-string-fields-is-set-to-is-equal-to)

I received a request to move Contains to the top of the list so it's the default filter. So I setup Filterable() as follows:

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(ops => ops
          .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                  .Contains("Contains")
                  .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                  .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                  .StartsWith("Starts with")
                  .EndsWith("Ends with")
                  .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                  .IsNull("Is null")
                  .IsNotNull("Is not null")
                  .IsEmpty("Is empty")
                  .IsNotEmpty("Is not empty")
                  )))
```

Unfortunately this does nothing to the order or default filter. However, if I remove just one option so the filter list is incomplete (it can be any option, say IsEmpty for example), then everything shows up in the proper order.

For example, with IsEmpty gone:

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(ops => ops
          .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                  .Contains("Contains")
                  .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                  .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                  .StartsWith("Starts with")
                  .EndsWith("Ends with")
                  .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                  .IsNull("Is null")
                  .IsNotNull("Is not null")
                  .IsNotEmpty("Is not empty")
                  )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the fascinating world of Kendo! :D I had the very same issue in October 2016. This is what the support replied:

> This is so, because when all the operators are present the default order is used. This is how the grid filter serialization is implemented.

The only reasonable choice you have, is to skip at least one filter operator.